# Отправка данных методом POST через HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, веб-сервер, httpurlconnection

5 EditText-ов и кнопка, отправляющая введенные данные. Пытаюсь отправлять методом POST но видимо, что-то где-то не выполняется. Отследить код никак не могу, программирую с телефона. Массив вывожу в тосте. Проблем со сбором информации, нет. Дело в отправке. Помогите разобраться. Код:

```
public class AddRegisterActivity extends Activity {
 String server_name = "http://dev.pareto-marketing.ru";

 String name_data, adress_data, login_data, password_data, info_data;

 EditText name_edit, adress_edit, password_edit, login_edit, info_edit;

 Button btn_add;

 AddG add_to;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.addregxml);
name_edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_edit);
adress_edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.adress_edit);
password_edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_edit);
login_edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_edit);
info_edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.info_edit);
btn_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

btn_add.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v)
{
try
{
add_to = new AddG();
add_to.execute();
name_data = name_edit.getText().toString();
login_data  = login_edit.getText().toString();
password_data = password_edit.getText().toString();
info_data = info_edit.getText().toString();
adress_data = adress_edit.getText().toString();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
}
});  
}

   private class AddG extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
String data;
String name_data, adress_data, login_data, password_data, info_data;
StringBuilder sb;
HttpURLConnection conn;

protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

try
{ 

data =
URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") 
+ "=" +
URLEncoder.encode(name_data, "UTF-8")
+ "&" +
URLEncoder.encode("adress", "UTF-8") 
+ "=" + 
URLEncoder.encode(adress_data, "UTF-8") 
+ "&" +
URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") 
+ "=" + 
URLEncoder.encode(password_data, "UTF-8")
+ "&" +
URLEncoder.encode("login", "UTF-8") 
+ "=" +
URLEncoder.encode(login_data, "UTF-8")
+ "&" + 
URLEncoder.encode("info", "UTF-8") 
+ "=" +
URLEncoder.encode(info_data, "UTF-8");

URL url_post = new URL(server_name+"/access/index.php?add");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url_post.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

writer.write(data);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
conn.connect();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
return data;
    }

protected void onPostExecute(String data) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Send to the server... " + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
}
```

Comment: Может надо mime type вашей посылки где-то указать `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. А то POST-ы двух видов бывают как минимум. И у них разный mime. Кто знает какой там по-умолчанию

Comment: @Sergey, а как его указать? или лучше не дадите ссылку на какую нибудь статью где прям все описано, до мелочей?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily